# Do antibodies to an arbovirus in a bloodmeal reduce vector competence?

Tags: literature, antibody, mosquitoes

When we conduct mosquito infection studies we typically mix blood and virus rather than using viraemic blood from naturally infected hosts. I'm looking for a paper I read some years ago which demonstrated that virus mixed with blood containing antibodies to that virus (*not* to mosquito midgut or salivary gland antigens) resulted in a lower proportion of infectious vectors than virus mixed with blood that does not contain those antigens. Unfortunately I don't seem to have kept a copy and now every search I conduct only throws up results to the aforementioned studies of anti-midgut or anti-SG antibodies. The nearest thing I can find is [this](https://elischolar.library.yale.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1188&context=ysphtdl), which looks at inhibition during intrathoracic inoculation (a completely different route of infection which is not particularly realistic, although we sometimes use it to boost the infection rate).